# How to perform a serial number search?

Tags: search, system-information, serial-number

I am looking for a way to search the serial number (of Apple products such as iPhones, iPads, Macs, etc.), and get information about the original configuration of that specific device.

I am aware of [this](https://support.apple.com/specs/) (or the [JSON version](https://km.support.apple.com/kb/index?page=categorydata&serialnumber=SERIALNUMBER&callback=ACSpecSearch.categoryDataProcess)) page of Apple's site that allows you to get the specs page of the product from the serial number you search, but I would like to get the specific configuration of that particular device.

For example, if I search my serial number for the MacBook Pro 2017 with 3.5 GHz Core i7, 16GB of Memory, and 1TB storage, I get a [general page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP755?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) without any of the information above. The page lists all the possible configurations instead of the specific configuration of my MacBook Pro.

**Is there some way to search a serial number and get information about the configuration of a specific device?**

Comment: Josh, are you asking because you have a specific device you need to check, or because you want to be able to check the original configuration of any device based on serial number?

Comment: @Monomeeth The latter, I often help people with tech support over the phone and would like to get all the information about the product (much like Apple Support does minus the sensitive info like Apple ID, of course) from their serial number instead of having them go through the process of giving all the information.  JSON is helpful because I can program it. Currently, I use a custom Apple Script diagnostic program that basically exports a lot of the information in `System Information.app` but, of course, that only works on macOS.

Comment: a good tool to use is etrececk. It will give you the current configuration.  http://etrecheck.com/   

   Run etrecheck.   The first five runs are free.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for something on Apple’s site, I do not know of one. However, EveryMac.com has a lookup search that I have had a pretty good success with. You can look Apple products up by serial number, model number, EMC number, or a number of other identification numbers on [this search page](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/).

Comment: Thank you, but this gets the same/similar information as the one listed in question and as a result does not give specific configuration details.

Comment: @Josh I was worried that would be the case